# SharePoint Designer 2013 -> REST Service Connection -> SoapException

Tags: rest, sharepoint, nullreferenceexception, designer, soapexception

Hy

In SharePoint Designer 2013:

- I'm adding a REST Service Connection to a REST Service hosted in my Intranet, which has Basic Authentication.

When I use this Data Connection as a DataList (for example on my SharePoint HomePage), i get the following Exception (in the Designer):

- The Server returned a non-specific error when trying to get data from the data source.

When I look at the SharePoint Logs, I see the following Exception:

SOAP exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetHierarchicalXPathNavigator(IHierarchicalDataSource ds)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigatorInternal()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.WebPartPagesWebService.GetDataFromDataSourceControl(String dscXml, String contextUrl)  0152039d-7db3-20a8-718f-0c727b68e96b

When I open the REST URL in my Web-Browser, everything works fine.

By the way, I've already enabled the intranet-calls, so this isn't the problem:

```
$farm=get-spfarm
$farm.properties.disableintranetcalls=$false
$farm.properties.disableintranetcallsfromapps=$false
$farm.Update()
```

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards,

Peter

Comment: The old "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error means that something is being used that hasn't been initialised. The most likely case is that the problem is within the REST service and not something you're doing.